# jQuery plugin to draw, resize and move boxes

Tags: jquery, drawing, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

I'm developing a page where I can draw boxes, resize them (pulling edges or corners) and move them by dragging (and I also need a zooming function, but this is another problem).

I found individual jQuery plugins to make each task but they do not live together well (e.g. when I try to resize, a new box is drawn...).

Is there an all-in-one plugin for my purpose?

EDIT:
I use ui.draggable and ui.resizable; this is the drawing plugin: [boxer](http://jsbin.com/azare)

Comment: Why don't you add them all in your page. Why do you want to merge them.

Comment: Because when I start moving a box, the drawing plugin starts as well and draws another box.

Comment: Ohh, I am not sure if it is because of the programming flaw. You must revisit you events.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to initiate resizing function (trigger handle drag) for resizable jQuery UI elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831361/how-to-initiate-resizing-function-trigger-handle-drag-for-resizable-jquery-ui)

Answer (score 1):

There is a canvas plugin for this kind of stuff that might help: http://www.websanova.com/plugins/websanova/paint

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation to see if there is a way to return false on the drawing plugin. Essentially you will want to put an if/else statement in the callback hook of the drawing function that checks to see if you are in a place where you should instead be invoking resize.

Make sense?

Comment: Yes, I'll do that if there are no other ways, but I'm not so aware of jQuery programming that I'm afraid of putting my hands inside a plugin...