# How to initiate resizing function (trigger handle drag) for resizable jQuery UI elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, event-handling, resize

Currently dynamically creating a [resizable](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/) element on`mousedown` when I click the screen.

jQuery UI auto adds handles to allow the user to click and drag to resize the element afterward.

I would like to trigger the handle so that as long as the user hasn't triggered `mouseup` they'll already be resizing the newly created element.

I can't find anything in the documentation that shows what events get triggered upon clicking those handles. I have tried executing `mousedown` and `click` on the handle after the element is created, placed on screen, and set as `resizable`. Neither of these worked.

Does anyone know how to trigger the start of the resize action? Alternatively if anyone knows how to log jQuery UI events I can use that to view what actions occur when the handles get clicked, follow the same path, and post my results here.

Comment: [Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hTkDF/) for this question. I haven't figured out how to trigger the drag as part of the original click ([jquery.simulate.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/tests/jquery.simulate.js) might be useful).

Answer (score 6):

The fiddle in the answer from [Michael L](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15871032/1300910) covers the essentials but still contains some bugs/limitations. Therefore I'm adding my modified version here as an answer.

**HTML**

```
<div id='container'></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

.block {
    position: absolute;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#container").on("mousedown", function(event){
    if (event.target !== this) {
        return;
    }
    var $target = $(event.target),
        $block = $("<div />")
            .addClass("block")
            .css({
                top: event.pageY - $target.offset().top,
                left: event.pageX - $target.offset().left
            })
            .resizable()
            .draggable({ containment: $target });
    $target.append($block);
    simulateHandleEvent($block, "se", event);
})

function simulateHandleEvent($item, handle, event){
    $item.find(".ui-resizable-" + handle)
        .trigger("mouseover")
        .trigger({
            type: "mousedown", 
            which: 1,
            pageX: event.pageX,
            pageY: event.pageY
    });
}
```

Check out [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UMKjm/)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and finally figured out the answer.  You have to pass in additional information to the `trigger()` function.  See [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hTfmM/19/).